# jQuery on click have to click twice for modal dialog to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Im using Dialog. When I click to open Dialog, I always have to click twice. I have tried many many solutions but Its not working.

```
jQuery(result).on('click', function() {
  jQuery(why).dialog({
    create: function (event, ui) {
      jQuery(".ui-corner-all").css('border-radius','0px !important');
    },
    autoOpen: true,
    title: "Whois Info",
    width: 1170,
    height: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Close: function() {jQuery(this).dialog("close");return false;}
    }
   });
 });
```

Comment: you don't need to initialize the dialog each and every time on the button click. Move the initialization part into document.ready function. Then inside the click function just write code to make the dialog visible.

Comment: Sound like a solution, but can you give me an example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to initialize the dialog each and every time on the button click. Move the initialization part into document.ready function. Then inside the click function just write code to make the dialog visible.

something like:

```
$( function() {
jQuery("#id").dialog({
    create: function (event, ui) {
      jQuery(".ui-corner-all").css('border-radius','0px !important');
    },
    autoOpen: true,
    title: "Whois Info",
    width: 1170,
    height: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Close: function() {jQuery(this).dialog("close");return false;}
    }
   });

jQuery(result).on('click', function() {
   jQuery("#id).dialog('open');
});

});
```

Comment: Ok, I moved your example code to document.ready function, but now i got error: Uncaught ReferenceError: why is not defined. I think that result gonna give me the same error. why and result is defined in another function, how can I solve that, thanks.

Comment: you can replace why with your dialog div id

Comment: Hmmmmm Ok, but Im declaring this in another function: var why = '#why' + (index > 0 ? index : '');

Comment: then make the variable why global

Comment: Ok, i made the variable global, but now i get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined

Comment: please just make the variable declaration alone global not the initialization

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157063/discussion-between-nishad-k-ahamed-and-tony).

Comment: I made variable declaration alone, but stil not working. Im in the chat now :)